# ComboBox DropDown where user cannot enter text

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, combobox

I have a Windows Form with a `DataGridView` and a `ComboBox`.  When a user clicks a row in the DGV, I want the `ComboBox` text to display the value in the row whether the value exists in the `ComboBox` or not.  However, I also want users to be able to select items in the `ComboBox` without the ability to enter custom text.

Changing the `DropDownStyle` to `DropDownList` will not work because then I will not be able to programatically enter values that don't exist.

One idea I had was to change the style to `DropDownList` and temporarily add custom items and then remove them when they are no longer selected in the DGV, but I was hoping for a more elegant solution.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: it almost sounds like you need 2 cbos, one for Std picks and one for Custom.

Comment: Bound or unbound mode? What do you have in the combo.Items? Are you using `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the DataError event to your advantage here and add the missing item to the collection by casting the *cell* to a DataGridViewComboBoxCell and add the missing item to its collection:

```
public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();

  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Columns.Add("C1");

  DataRow dr1 = dt.NewRow();
  dr1[0] = "ccc";
  dt.Rows.Add(dr1);
  DataRow dr2 = dt.NewRow();
  dr2[0] = "xxx";
  dt.Rows.Add(dr2);

  dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

  var dgvCB = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
  dgvCB.Items.AddRange(new string[] { "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd" });
  dgv.Columns.Add(dgvCB);
  dgv.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "C1";

  dgv.DataError += dgv_DataError;
  dgv.DataSource = dt;
}

void dgv_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e) {
  if (e.ColumnIndex == 0) {
    string value = dt.Rows[e.RowIndex][e.ColumnIndex].ToString();
    var dgvCB = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
    if (!dgvCB.Items.Contains(value)) {
      dgvCB.Items.Add(value);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about creating the `combobox_KeyPress` and then add the line `e.KeyChar = Nothing` that will prevent any keystrokes into the box

Comment: This is an interesting solution, but I would also need to handle other things like the Delete key (not handled by KeyPress) and Copy+Paste.

Comment: It wouldn't be to difficult to handle those key strokes, but I feel this maybe the best way to prevent a user from entering their own info